# Form submit authentication from aspx to php via post

Tags: php, html, asp.net, forms, post

Any help would be appreciated. I am trying to SSO from our portal using an ASPX page that submits username and password to the form on my PHP login page for another site.  I've successfully pulled this off to other pages but can't get it to work now.

This is the block of code from the ASPX page.

```
  case "k": // Kivuto
  {
%>
<body onload="document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit()">
<form name="login" action="https://webapps.someschool.edu/sso/kivuto.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="ccid" value="<%=strUser%>">
<input type="hidden" name="passwd" value="<%=strPass%>">
</form>
</body>

<%
    break;
```

This is the block of code from the PHP page.

```
<form name="login" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <?php echo $_error; ?><br />
        <p><h2>Some School</h2></p><br />
        <p>Username<br />
        <input type="text" name="ccid" size="25" /></p>
        <p>Password:<br />
        <input type="password" name="passwd" size="25" /></p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" /> 
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear" />
</form>
```

When I call the case k it does open the kivuto.php page but doesn't auto-submit.  I even put a php var_dump ($_POST) in the body and it shows the correct username and password is getting to the kivuto.php page from the ASPX page, just not logging me in.

Any ideas?

Thanks,